# mpiexec: starting program with zero processes

Tags: c, process, mpi, mpiexec

I want to have an error message and exit normally in case `-np` is set to zero on the command line. Is there any way to do this? It seems like the program stops working without even starting.

Answer (score 2):

Zero number of processes indeed means it does not start any process at all. How can you have any output if you have no process to create it? No process is just no process. Nothing is running. Like if you don't run the mpiexec at all.

I don't get what kind of error message would you expect to see. Perhaps you actually want 1 process?

I just tested mpiexec coming with OpenMPI on my computer an it starts 1 process if you requests `-np 0`. Other implementations might behave differently.

Comment: I just wanted it for the sake of being "user friendly". I don't want others to bug it on purpose.

With zero processes, it blocks the command line and the only option i have is to kill it.

I'm using plain mpi.

Edit: With control c i get a message:
(mpiexec 440): mpiexec: failed to obtain sock from manager

Comment: You must really describe which MPI library you use, what kind of program you try to run and what exactly happens and what you wanted to happen. For example, do you use MPICH or OpenMPI or something else? On which operating system? Even if you will make it do what you want in one case it will be unpredictable in others.

Comment: Wow, mpich handles '0' horriblly, with a buch of Hydra errors and a segfault.  I'll open a ticket